# Get all the values ​of the key "kilos" of all objects

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I have this

```
data = [
   0: {kilos: 10},
   1: {other:1, kilos: 5},
   2: {other:2, kilos:6}
]
```

I want to get all the values ​​that are inside the "kilos" keys and then make a sum, but I have no idea how to do it

Data comes from firestore
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have an array `data`, then `data.reduce((l, r) => l + r.kilos || 0, 0)`.

```js
data = [
   {kilos: 10},
   {other:1, kilos: 5},
   {other:2, kilos:6}
]

console.log(data.reduce((l, r) => l + r.kilos || 0, 0))
```

Or with `lodash`:

```js
data = [
   {kilos: 10},
   {other:1, kilos: 5},
   {other:2, kilos:6}
]

console.log(_.sumBy(data, o => o.kilos || 0))

console.log(_.sumBy(data, 'kilos'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const data = [
       {kilos: 10},
       {other:1, kilos: 5},
       {other:2, kilos:6}
    ]
    data.forEach((value) => {
      const kilos = value.kilos;
      console.log(kilos);  
      // here you can add other sums;
    });
```